# PDF memory warning/crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, pdf-generation

Despite research on Google, and on So and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html. I still cant find an answer to this problem with my app. My app generates a PDF drawn into a web view as soon as the view is loaded. The problem is I can only generate about 8 pages on an iPhone 4s, 14 on an iPhone 5 before I receive a memory warning and crashes.

`ICPDFEICRInspection1` 2,3,4 etc are large views/xibs being drawn into the web view

At the moment The app generates all the pages and then displays the entire document in a `webView`.

**My Question:**  How can I change this so im only drawing one page at a time as the user scrolls, rather than loading it all up first in memory,  looping through content drawing it one page at a time

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
LogCmd();

 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 if (self.pdfData != nil && self.viewHasUnloaded == YES) {
    self.viewHasUnloaded = NO;
    [self.webView loadData:self.pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    }
   }



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {

  LogCmd();
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  if (self.pdfData == nil) {



    // Generate PDF
     [ICUtils showProgressViewWithTitle:@"Generating PDF. This may take a minute..."];
     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(generatePdf) withObject:nil];
  }
 }

  - (void)generatePdf
   {
   NSMutableArray *pagesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

  if ([self.certificate.certificateType.title isEqualToString:@"EICR"]) {
    [pagesArray addObject:[[ICPDFEICRPage1 alloc] initWithCertificate:self.certificate]];
    [pagesArray addObject:[[ICPDFEICRPage2 alloc] initWithCertificate:self.certificate]];
    [self addObservationsToPagesArray:pagesArray];
    [self addDistributionBoardsToPagesArray:pagesArray];
    [pagesArray addObject:[[ICPDFEICRInspection alloc] initWithCertificate:self.certificate]];
    [pagesArray addObject:[[ICPDFEICRInspectionPage1 alloc] initWithCertificate:self.certificate]];
    [pagesArray addObject:[[ICPDFEICRInspectionPage2 alloc] initWithCertificate:self.certificate]];
    [pagesArray addObject:[[ICPDFEICRInspectionPage3 alloc] initWithCertificate:self.certificate]];
    [pagesArray addObject:[[ICPDFEICRPageFinal alloc] initWithCertificate:self.certificate]];
   }

  // Set page count on all pages
int pageNumber = 0;
for (ICCertificateComponent *page in pagesArray) {
    page.pageNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ++pageNumber];
    page.pageCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pagesArray.count];
  }

   NSData *pdfData = [self createPdfWithPages:pagesArray];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pdfDone:) withObject:pdfData waitUntilDone:YES];

  }
  }
     - (void)pdfDone:(NSData *)data
   {
self.pdfData = data;
[self.webView loadData:self.pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
[ICUtils removeProgressView];
 }

  - (NSData *)createPdfWithPages:(NSArray *)pages
  {
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array

  NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

  ICCertificateComponent *firstPage = [pages objectAtIndex:0];

   UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, firstPage.contentView.bounds, nil);

  for (int i = 0; i < pages.count; i++) {
    ICCertificateComponent *thisPage = [pages objectAtIndex:i];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(thisPage.contentView.bounds, nil);

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [thisPage.contentView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
   }

 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

return pdfData;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating all the PDF data into an in-memory data structure which is a bad idea. Try using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` to write the PDF data to a file first. When you are done, load this into the web view.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Im not sure how to go about this any advice/elaboration greatly appreciated

Answer (score -2):

Some possible ways:

1. UITableView. Each cell holds a page. iOS asks you to create cells and therefore pages on demand, and only keeps enough to fill the screen.  Problem is the rendering of a PDF page takes significant time, and that will make scrolling jerky.
2. UICollectionView. The same but allows more flexibility, e.g. left to right pages.
3. CATiledLayer. Like Google Maps lets you scroll smoothly by rendering in the background. More complex, and actually not so great in practice for displaying documents, I found.
4. Create a PDF file for webView to render, rather than rendering all pages to memory. The system will take care of memory, and it'll scroll smoothly without artefacts. Probably your best bet if the PDF pages don't change.

Comment: web View is rendering it currently

Comment: Yes, but to prepare for that he's rendering PDF to memory rather than to a file.

Comment: Ah ok my bad, any advice to write to file?

Comment: See where you are using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`? There's also a `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile`.  Give it a filepath rather than an NSData, and you should be on your way.

Comment: Im still no further forward with this, I really dont understand.  I have changed to `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` & ` NSURL *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html"];` but getting incompatible  pointer type errors, bad access errors urrrrgh!

Comment: Path is a string, not an NSURL.  
And `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource...` is for reading files from your readonly applications resource directory. You need to write to a temporary directory.
Try `NSTemporaryDirectory()`.
And you want to create a PDF file, not a HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately without an example code to illustrate your advice its difficult for me or other users of SO who come across this question to fully undertand it